# Using Python, Get Partial Sum of DF column based on a condition from another sorted column

Tags: python, dataframe

[DataFrame in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYj56.png)

I need to find out total invoice value for each supplier and create a new dataframe with unique supplier names as follows.

[Final Output desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jkl6j.png)

Comment: Please post the data in a minimally reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Also, show the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sum_by_supplier = (df.groupby('Supplier Name')['Invoice Value'].sum()).reset_index()
```